# Remove all the button from a kivy dropdown

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I'm new with Python and I tried to sort out this problem, but unlikely I wasn't able to do this.
Dropdown is dinamically populated via mqtt (here for instance is mosquito) and after the selection of a value I need to change Screen and when I return in the screen with the dropdown it should be empty.

Someone have some idea for doing it?
Thank you in advance.

main.py

```
#-*-coding:utf8;-*-
#qpy:2
#qpy:kivy
#!/usr/bin/python
#@@@@@@ -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
#from kivy.properties import DictProperty

import xmlrpclib
import calendar
import datetime
from urllib3.util.timeout import current_time
from datetime import date, time, timedelta
import locale
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton

from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from threading import Thread
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time
from time import sleep
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser



class CustomDropDownChip(DropDown):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomDropDownChip, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        notes = chip_list
        for note in notes:
            btn = Button(text='%s' % note, size_hint_y=None, height=int(Window.height)/10)
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.select('CHIP: ' + btn.text))
            self.add_widget(btn)

class StartScreen(Screen):
    pass

class InsertBox(Screen):
    global chip_list
    chip_list = []
    global chip_list_empty
    chip_list_empty = []
    global connected_flag
    consommables = ListProperty([])

    def buttons_down(self):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        app.chip_value = self.ids.id_chip.text
        app.InsertSelection = 'InsertBoxConfirm'

    def on_connect(self, mqttc, obj, flags, rc):
        if rc==0:
            mqttc.connected_flag=True
            connected_flag = True
            print("connected OK")
        else:
            print("Bad connection Returned code=",rc)
    def on_disconnect(self, mqttc, obj, rc):
        pass

    def on_message(self, mqttc, obj, msg):
        response = str(msg.payload)
        if response not in chip_list:
            sleep(1)
            chip_list.append(response)
        if mqttc.connected_flag == False:
            mqttc.on_disconnect()
    def on_publish(self, mqttc, obj, mid):
        print("mid: "+str(mid))
    def on_subscribe(self, mqttc, obj, mid, granted_qos):
        print("Subscribed: "+str(mid)+" "+str(granted_qos))
    def on_log(self, mqttc, obj, level, string):
        print(string)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(InsertBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def stop_mqtt(self):
        mqttc.disconnect()
    def start_mqtt(self):
        self.read_chip()
    def read_chip(self, *args):
        global t
        t = Thread(target=self.read_).start()
    def read_(self):

        mqtt.Client.connected_flag=False#create flag in class
        connected_flag = False

        global mqttc
        mqttc = mqtt.Client(transport="websockets")
        mqttc.on_message = self.on_message
        mqttc.on_connect = self.on_connect
        mqttc.on_publish = self.on_publish
        mqttc.on_subscribe = self.on_subscribe
        mqttc.on_log = self.on_log
        mqttc.connect("test.mosquitto.org", 8080, 60)
        mqttc.subscribe("temp/random", 0)
        mqttc.loop_forever()



    def consume(self, *args):
        while self.consommables and time() < (Clock.get_time() + MAX_TIME):
            item = self.consommables.pop(0)  # i want the first one
            label = Factory.MyLabel(text=item)
            self.root.ids.id_chip.text = label #add_widget(label)

#    @classmethod
    def reset_chip_list(self):
        chip_list = chip_list_empty


class InsertBoxConfirm(Screen):
    def buttons_set(self):
        InsertBox.buttons_set()
    def buttons_reset(self):
        InsertBox.buttons_reset()

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):

    def SetChip(self, value):
        pass

class testdropdownApp(App):
    title = "Kivy Drop-Down List Demo"
    chip_list = chip_list_empty
    chip_value = ''

    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testdropdownApp().run()
```

testdropdown.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<CustomDropDownChip>:
    on_select:
        app.root.ids.InsertBox.ids.id_chip.text = '{}'.format(args[1])
        app.root.SetChip(args[1])


<StartScreen>:
    name: 'StartScreen'
    Button:
        text: 'Start'
        on_release:
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            root.manager.transition.duration = 0
            root.manager.current = 'InsertBox'


<InsertBox>:
    name: 'InsertBox'
    id: test00 
    on_enter:
        root.reset_chip_list()
        root.start_mqtt()
    on_leave:
        root.stop_mqtt()

    GridLayout:
        rows: 2
        id: test01
        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            size_hint_y: .27
            padding: 5
            Button:
                id: id_chip
                text: 'Select chip'
#                    size_hint_y: .5
                spacing: 5
                on_release: Factory.CustomDropDownChip().open(self)

        GridLayout:
            size_hint_y: .2
            height: .15
            cols: 2
            BoxLayout:
                padding: 5
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                size: root.size
                pos: root.pos
                spacing: 5
#                height: .15
                Button:
                    text: "Back"
                    on_press:
                        root.reset_chip_list()
                        root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                        root.manager.transition.duration = 0
                        root.manager.current = 'StartScreen'
                Button:
                    text: 'OK'
                    on_press:
                        root.buttons_down()
                        root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                        root.manager.transition.duration = 0
                        root.manager.current = 'InsertBoxConfirm'

<InsertBoxConfirm>:
    name: 'InsertBoxConfirm'
    on_pre_enter:
        id_chip_label.text = app.chip_value
    GridLayout:
        rows: 2
        id: id_InsertBoxConfirm
        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            size_hint_y: .27
            padding: 5
            Label:
                id: id_chip_label
                text: 'valore CHIP'

        GridLayout:
            size_hint_y: .2
            height: .15
            cols: 1
            BoxLayout:
                padding: 5
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                size: root.size
                pos: root.pos
                spacing: 5
                Button:
                    text: 'OK'
                    id: button_ok
                    on_press:
                        root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                        root.manager.transition.duration = 0
                        root.manager.current = 'InsertBox'


<MyScreenManager>:
    StartScreen:
        id: 'StartScreen'
        name: 'StartScreen'
    InsertBox:
        id: InsertBox
        name: 'InsertBox'
    InsertBoxConfirm:
        id: InsertBoxConfirm
        name: 'InsertBoxConfirm'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the overview, snippets, and example for details.

## Overview

### kv file

1. Remove import statement, `#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory`
2. Move `root.reset_chip_list()` from `on_enter:` to `on_leave:`
3. Replace `Factory.CustomDropDownChip().open(self)` with a new callbackmethod, `root.create_open_customdropdown(self)`
4. Remove `root.reset_chip_list()` from `on_press:` Back Button because when we leave the screen, it will automatically fired `on_leave:` event.
5. Replace `app.chip_value` with `root.manager.chip_value` because we will be moving variable, `chip_value` from App class to root class.

### Snippet - kv file

```
            Button:
                id: id_chip
                text: 'Select chip'
                spacing: 5
                on_release:
                    root.create_open_customdropdown(self)
```

### Python Code

1. Add import statement, `from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty`
2. Remove variables (global chip_list; global chip_list_empty; global connected_flag) from `class InsertBox(Screen):`
3. Replace `chip_list = []` with `chip_list = ListProperty([])`; `chip_list_empty = []` with `chip_list_empty = ListProperty([])`; and add `connected_flag = BooleanProperty(False)`
4. Add ObjectProperty, `dropdown = ObjectProperty(None)` at class level of `class InsertBox(Screen):` so that we can use this to hook-up to the *CustomDropDownChip* object and remove it.
5. Implement a new method, create_open_customdropdown(self, instance): inside `class InsertBox(Screen):`
6. In methods, replace `chip_list` with `self.chip_list`; `chip_list_empty` with `self.chip_list_empty`; `connected_flag` with `self.connected_flag`
7. Remove `chip_list = chip_list_empty` from `class testdropdownApp():`
8. Move `chip_value = ''` from `class testdropdownApp()` to `class MyScreenManager():`
9. In `SetChip()` method, replace `pass` with `self.chip_value = value`
10. In *CustomDropDownChip*'s constructor, add `chip_list` as arguments; remove `notes = chip_list`; and replace `notes` with `chip_list`

### Snippet - Python code

```
class CustomDropDownChip(DropDown):
    def __init__(self, chip_list, **kwargs):
        super(CustomDropDownChip, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for note in chip_list:
            btn = Button(text='%s' % note, size_hint_y=None, height=int(Window.height)/10)
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.select('CHIP: ' + btn.text))
            self.add_widget(btn)
...
class InsertBox(Screen):
    consommables = ListProperty([])
    chip_list = ListProperty([])
    chip_list_empty = ListProperty([])
    connected_flag = BooleanProperty(False)
    dropdown = ObjectProperty(None)

    def create_open_customdropdown(self, instance):
        self.dropdown = CustomDropDownChip(self.chip_list)
        self.dropdown.open(instance)
...
    def reset_chip_list(self):
        print("\tlen(chip_list)=", len(self.chip_list))
        self.chip_list = self.chip_list_empty
        print("\tlen(chip_list)=", len(self.chip_list))

        if self.dropdown is not None:
            self.remove_widget(self.dropdown)
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from datetime import time
from threading import Thread
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time
from time import sleep
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, ObjectProperty

MAX_TIME = 1/60.


class CustomDropDownChip(DropDown):
    def __init__(self, chip_list, **kwargs):
        super(CustomDropDownChip, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for note in chip_list:
            btn = Button(text='%s' % note, size_hint_y=None, height=int(Window.height)/10)
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.select('CHIP: ' + btn.text))
            self.add_widget(btn)


class StartScreen(Screen):
    pass


class InsertBox(Screen):
    consommables = ListProperty([])
    chip_list = ListProperty([])
    chip_list_empty = ListProperty([])
    connected_flag = BooleanProperty(False)
    dropdown = ObjectProperty(None)

    def create_open_customdropdown(self, instance):
        self.dropdown = CustomDropDownChip(self.chip_list)
        self.dropdown.open(instance)

    def buttons_down(self):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        app.InsertSelection = 'InsertBoxConfirm'

    def on_connect(self, mqttc, obj, flags, rc):
        if rc==0:
            mqttc.connected_flag = True
            self.connected_flag = True
            print("connected OK")
        else:
            print("Bad connection Returned code=",rc)

    def on_disconnect(self, mqttc, obj, rc):
        pass

    def on_message(self, mqttc, obj, msg):

        response = str(msg.payload)
        if response not in self.chip_list:
            sleep(1)
            self.chip_list.append(response)

        if mqttc.connected_flag == False:
            mqttc.on_disconnect()

    def on_publish(self, mqttc, obj, mid):
        print("mid: "+str(mid))

    def on_subscribe(self, mqttc, obj, mid, granted_qos):
        print("Subscribed: "+str(mid)+" "+str(granted_qos))

    def on_log(self, mqttc, obj, level, string):
        print(string)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(InsertBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def stop_mqtt(self):
        mqttc.disconnect()

    def start_mqtt(self):
        self.read_chip()

    def read_chip(self, *args):
        global t
        t = Thread(target=self.read_).start()

    def read_(self):

        mqtt.Client.connected_flag = False  # create flag in class
        self.connected_flag = False

        global mqttc
        mqttc = mqtt.Client(transport="websockets")
        mqttc.on_message = self.on_message
        mqttc.on_connect = self.on_connect
        mqttc.on_publish = self.on_publish
        mqttc.on_subscribe = self.on_subscribe
        mqttc.on_log = self.on_log
        mqttc.connect("test.mosquitto.org", 8080, 60)
        mqttc.subscribe("temp/random", 0)
        mqttc.loop_forever()

    def consume(self, *args):
        while self.consommables and time() < (Clock.get_time() + MAX_TIME):
            item = self.consommables.pop(0)  # i want the first one
            label = Factory.MyLabel(text=item)
            self.root.ids.id_chip.text = label #add_widget(label)

#    @classmethod
    def reset_chip_list(self):
        print("\tlen(chip_list)=", len(self.chip_list))
        self.chip_list = self.chip_list_empty
        print("\tlen(chip_list)=", len(self.chip_list))

        if self.dropdown is not None:
            self.remove_widget(self.dropdown)


class InsertBoxConfirm(Screen):
    def buttons_set(self):
        InsertBox.buttons_set()

    def buttons_reset(self):
        InsertBox.buttons_reset()


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    chip_value = ''

    def SetChip(self, value):
        self.chip_value = value


class testdropdownApp(App):
    title = "Kivy Drop-Down List Demo"

    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()

    def on_stop(self):
        self.root.ids.InsertBox.stop_mqtt()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    testdropdownApp().run()
```

### testdropdown.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0

<CustomDropDownChip>:
    on_select:
        app.root.ids.InsertBox.ids.id_chip.text = '{}'.format(args[1])
        app.root.SetChip(args[1])


<StartScreen>:
    name: 'StartScreen'
    Button:
        text: 'Start'
        on_release:
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            root.manager.transition.duration = 0
            root.manager.current = 'InsertBox'


<InsertBox>:
    name: 'InsertBox'
    id: test00
    on_enter:
        root.start_mqtt()
    on_leave:
        root.stop_mqtt()
        root.reset_chip_list()

    GridLayout:
        rows: 2
        id: test01
        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            size_hint_y: .27
            padding: 5
            Button:
                id: id_chip
                text: 'Select chip'
#                    size_hint_y: .5
                spacing: 5
                on_release:
                    root.create_open_customdropdown(self)

        GridLayout:
            size_hint_y: .2
            height: .15
            cols: 2
            BoxLayout:
                padding: 5
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                size: root.size
                pos: root.pos
                spacing: 5
#                height: .15
                Button:
                    text: "Back"
                    on_press:
                        root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                        root.manager.transition.duration = 0
                        root.manager.current = 'StartScreen'
                Button:
                    text: 'OK'
                    on_press:
                        root.buttons_down()
                        root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                        root.manager.transition.duration = 0
                        root.manager.current = 'InsertBoxConfirm'

<InsertBoxConfirm>:
    name: 'InsertBoxConfirm'
    on_pre_enter:
        id_chip_label.text = root.manager.chip_value

    GridLayout:
        rows: 2
        id: id_InsertBoxConfirm
        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            size_hint_y: .27
            padding: 5
            Label:
                id: id_chip_label
                text: 'valore CHIP'

        GridLayout:
            size_hint_y: .2
            height: .15
            cols: 1
            BoxLayout:
                padding: 5
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                size: root.size
                pos: root.pos
                spacing: 5
                Button:
                    text: 'OK'
                    id: button_ok
                    on_press:
                        root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                        root.manager.transition.duration = 0
                        root.manager.current = 'InsertBox'


<MyScreenManager>:
    StartScreen:
        id: 'StartScreen'
        name: 'StartScreen'
    InsertBox:
        id: InsertBox
        name: 'InsertBox'
    InsertBoxConfirm:
        id: InsertBoxConfirm
        name: 'InsertBoxConfirm'
```

## Output

[image: Img01]
[image: Img02]
[image: Img03]
[image: Img04]

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time and your precious, precise and detailed answer.. it works great..

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
for child in self.mydropdownsomething.children[:]:
    self.mydropdownsomething.remove_widget(child)
```

where mydropdownsomething is the object where you dynamically add your dropdownbuttons.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. but I'm not able to remove the buttons in the dropdown. I tried before with a piece of code like yours and now again. I modified the example in this way:

    def reset_chip_list(self):
#        chip_list = chip_list_empty
        for child in self.ids.id_chip.children[:]:
            self.ids.id_chip.remove_widget(child)

and when I return back on the same page I still found the previous value in the dropdown instead an empty list.